# Let ABCD be a parallelogram...

Tags: geometry

[image]

Let $ABCD$ be a parallelogram, $Q$ the midpoint of $AB$, $O$ the intersection point of the diagonals $AC$ and $BD$. The perpendicular raised on $AB$ at $Q$ intersects $AC$ at $N$ and $BD$ at $M$. Construct also $OP$ perpendicular to $AB$. 
Prove that: $$\frac1{QM}+\frac1{QN}=\frac{2}{OP}$$

Comment: Please don't dump unsourced, unmotivated problems here without any sign of having put any effort into solving them.

Answer (score 1):

Proving that $$\frac{1}{QM}+\frac{1}{QN}=\frac{2}{OP}$$ means proving that $$ OP = 2 \frac{QM\cdot QN}{QM + QN}$$ Let $\hat{ABD} = \hat{ABO} = \hat{ABM} = \alpha$, $\hat{BAO} = \hat{BAC} = \beta$ and $AB = a$. Now, $QM$ and $QN$ are perpendiculars to $AB$, $$QM = BQ\tan\alpha = \frac{a}{2}\tan\alpha$$ $$QN = AQ\tan\beta = \frac{a}{2}\tan\beta $$ So $$2 \frac{QM\cdot QN}{QM + QN} = 2\frac{\frac{a}{2}\tan\alpha\cdot \frac{a}{2}\tan\beta}{\frac{a}{2}\tan\alpha+\frac{a}{2}\tan\beta} = a\frac{\tan\alpha\cdot \tan\beta}{\tan\alpha + \tan\beta} $$
But as $OP$ is perpendicular to $AB$, $$OP=AO\sin\beta $$ Now for the $Sines' Law$ $$\frac{AO}{\sin\alpha} = \frac{AB}{\sin(\pi-\alpha-\beta)} \to AO = a\frac{\sin\alpha}{\sin(\alpha+\beta) }$$
$$ \to OP = AO\sin\beta = a\frac{\sin\alpha}{\sin(\alpha+\beta)}\sin\beta = a\frac{\sin\alpha\cdot \sin\beta}{\sin\alpha\cdot \cos\beta+\sin\beta\cos\alpha} $$
$$= a\frac{\sin\alpha\cdot \sin\beta}{\cos\alpha\cdot \cos\beta}\frac{\cos\alpha\cdot \cos\beta}{\sin\alpha\cdot \cos\beta+\sin\beta\cos\alpha} = a\frac{\tan\alpha\cdot \tan\beta}{\frac{\sin\alpha\cdot \cos\beta+\sin\beta\cos\alpha}{\cos\alpha\cdot \cos\beta}}$$
$$= a\frac{\tan\alpha\cdot \tan\beta}{\frac{\sin\alpha}{\cos\alpha}+\frac{\sin\beta}{\cos\beta}} = a\frac{\tan\alpha\cdot \tan\beta}{\tan\alpha + \tan\beta} = 2 \frac{QM\cdot QN}{QM + QN}$$ which concludes the proof.

Answer (score 1):

$$\triangle BPO \sim \triangle BQM \qquad \implies \qquad \frac{OP}{QM} = \frac{BP}{BQ} = \frac{BP}{AB/2} = 2\frac{BP}{AB}$$
$$\triangle APO \sim \triangle AQN \qquad \implies \qquad \frac{OP}{QN} = \frac{AP}{AQ} = \frac{AP}{AB/2} = 2\frac{AP}{AB}$$
So,
$$\frac{OP}{QM} + \frac{OP}{QN} = 2 \left( \frac{BP}{AB} + \frac{AP}{AB} \right) = 2 \frac{AB}{AB} = 2$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

It is enough to assume that $P\in A\vee B$ and that the line $O\vee N$ is parallel to $Q\vee P$, so you don't have to bother about orthogonality and can solve the problem in a relatively simple vector algebra setting. Assume the vertices of your parallelogram to be $A=e-f$, $B=e+f$, $C=-A$, $D=-B$ for given linearly independent vectors $e$, $f$. Then $Q=e$, and $P=e+\alpha f$ for some *given* $\alpha$.

**Followup**

We have  $N=\nu(e-f)$, $M=\mu(e+f)$ for certain $\nu$, $\mu$. It follows that $$N=\nu(e-f)=e-\sigma(e+\alpha f), \quad M=\mu(e+f)=e-\tau(e+\alpha f)$$
for certain $\sigma$, $\tau$. Since $e$ and $f$ are linearly independent we immediately infer $\nu=\alpha\sigma$ and $\mu=-\alpha\tau$, and in a second step that
$$\sigma={1\over 1+\alpha}, \quad \tau={1\over 1-\alpha}\ .$$
This implies
$${OP\over QN}+{OP\over QM}={1\over\sigma}+{1\over\tau}=2\ ,$$
as claimed.